# can we use break statement in if-else statement in python

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

I am trying to use break statement in below code snippet, but i am getting an error "break is outside loop".

what I am trying to do here is when m1=n2, i want to display that matrix multiplication is possible and when m1 !=n2, i want to display the message saying multiplication is not possible and program should stop after displaying the message. any suggestions as to how can i do it.

code snippet is as below -

```
if (n1 == m2):
    print ("matrix multiplication is possible")
    
else:
    print ("matrix multiplication is not possible")
```

... where should i put break statement here?

Comment: nowhere, why do you even want to do such thing this makes no sense and your code works as is...

Comment: No need of break. You are not using a loop. It will automatically terminate

Comment: ```break``` is used to come out of loops (```for``` and ```while```). You don't have any loops in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`break` and `continue` should be used in the loop body. You can use `return` in functions to terminate it or `exit()` to stop running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Break is only used for loops such as: while, do while, switch

If you want to end your if statements from executing, you can use return;
By adding `return;` all else if statements after it won't execute. It's similar to break but not the same :)
Like this;

```
def myFunction(n1,m2):
    if n1 == m2:
        print ("matrix multiplication is possible")
    
    else:
        print ("matrix multiplication is not possible")
    
    return None #Not really needed, since functions return None by default

myFunction(2,2)
```

Comment: This of course requires the entire code being in a function

Comment: True. If you still want to do it this way you might want to put everything in a function and then call it. Just edited it that way

Comment: When are condition is met, no other part is executed in `if-elif-else`. If `if` is True, Python skips `elif` and `else` blocks.